# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.debugf. Glassfish 4.1, HIbernate 5.2, Spring 4.3

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, maven, glassfish

Não consigo subir uma aplicação no Glassfish 4.1. Me parece que o problema é a dependência **org.jboss.logging** já adicionei ela ao projeto na versão 3.3.0 mas o erro persiste. O estranho é que a mesma aplicação "roda" tranquilamente no Apache Tomcat 8.

Stack trace:

```
2016-12-28T12:07:45.594-0300|Grave: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'notaFiscalDAOImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'firebirdSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [br/com/hopelingerie/appcheckouttransporte/config/FirebirdHibernateConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1225)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:552)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:5394)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:743)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5963)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:691)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:1024)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2286)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1932)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:139)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:500)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Dependências (pom.xml):

```xml
<properties>
    <!-- Generic properties -->
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <spring-framework.version>4.3.5.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>
    <!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
    <hibernate.version>5.2.5.Final</hibernate.version>
    <!-- JSF Version -->
    <jsf.version>2.2.14</jsf.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring and Transactions -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring ORM support -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.firebirdsql.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaybird-jdk18</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
        <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- JSF Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jsf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${jsf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: A parte relevante da mensagem de erro é o "*Error creating bean with name 'firebirdSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [br/com/hopelingerie/appcheckouttransporte/config/FirebirdHibernateConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;I)V*" - Ou seja, parece ser um problema de dependências do maven.

Comment: Oi @VictorStafusa. De fato se trata de um problema de dependências. Alguma das dependências declaradas no meu pom.xml depende da org.jboss.logging mas não sei qual ou quais. Já adicionei manualmente a seguinte dependência :

    <dependency>
 <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
 <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
 <version>3.3.0.Final</version>
 </dependency>

post: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37825307/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-jboss-logging-logger-debug-spring-4-3-hibernat